# r: do not show warnings

Tags: r, warnings

I use R in another program, named galaxy. In galaxy it is not possible to run a Rscript within warning. My question is, is there a option in R, that do not shows any warnings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See `warn` under `?options`. You may want to set a negative value for this one. See also: `example(warnings)`.