# for-loops with print() or cat()

Tags: r, for-loop

Within a for loop, you have to use print() or cat() to display the content of an object in the console of R. Outside the for-loop, you can display the content of an object just by providing its name. Why does this not work in for loops? What is the underlying reason? I have searched for an explanation in the Web, but couldn't find an anwer! Thank's for all efforts in advance!

Example:

```r
obj <- "My Name"
obj
for (i in 1:3) {
   obj   # does not display the "My Name"
   print(obj)   # displays "My Name"
}
```

Comment: I edited out the references to RStudio, since I have no expectation that this is about the R language itself, not specific to the IDE. If I'm mistaken, my apologies.

Comment: The only time an object is `print`ed on the console (or stdout) is either (a) explicit use of the `print(.)` function; or (b) the last expression of something that returns a value, whether explicitly via `return(.)` or implicitly as the last expression of the block, and that block's return value is not captured into a variable. `function`s, for instance, will return the last expression executed unless there is an explicit `return(something)`; `local(.)` behaves this way as well as well. A `for` loop will never "return" anything, even if one attempts an explicit `return(.)`.

Comment: To demonstrate my notion of "last expression of something", see that `{1; 2;}` "returns" `2`, and since we don't capture it and the 2 is the last expression in the `{`-block. Alternatively, `aa <- {1; 2;}` still returns the `2` (stored into `aa`) but since it was captured, it is not `print`ed on the console. To confuse things a little, `(aa <- {1; 2;})` _will_ `print` it, because assignment via `<-` or `=` is still an expression that returns something, but it is `invisible(..)` and therefore not printed to the console.

Comment: In the end, the whole notion in R of `print` being done automatically on objects is purely (in my mind, at least) a convenience for interactive work. When a user is looping over something, it makes less sense to print the value of every object that is in the loop, requiring instead that in these iteration-moments the user must explicitly choose to `print(.)` something, as in your `for` loop in the question.

Comment: Hmm, despite the exact match for OP's question with the **title** of the marked duplicate, none of the answers there really get at the **why**. I would suggest keeping it a dupe, but if anyone wants to add an answer there focusing on *"What is the underlying reason?"*, I would gladly upvote.

Comment: Thank's for the response, but I have seen the answer pointed to before. So I would like to know why automated printing is turned off in a for loop or function. Is there a deeper reaseon for this or is it just programmed this way? Would be nice if someone could comment on this!
Best Regards 
Roland Alexander

Comment: I don't have a good reference to point you to for this, but I think r2evans is give you an answer to that that matches my thoughts as well: The general rule is that nothing prints to the console without a function like `print` or `cat` or `message` or `warning`. The creators of R have made an exception - when you're using R *interactively* and you are at the top level (not in a function or loop), entering `x`  on the console calls `print(x)`. Think of that as the exception. In programmatic use, like in a function or loop, R doesn't print unless you tell it to.

Comment: And I'd add that `print` is over-used, often `warning()` or `message()` [would be a better choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36699272/903061). These are nice because the user can customize them, with options and wrappers (like `suppressMessages()`), and when authors do use `print()` it can be a pain to work around it - [we get questions like these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38118095/903061). `cat` is even worse for this.

Comment: Re-stating, *in programmatic use, like in a function or loop, R doesn't print unless you tell it to.* And that's good. Your program **shouldn't** do anything unless you explicitly tell it to!

Comment: High Gregor, 
thank' for your respone which helps me to understand what is going on. Nevertheless, when you say "using R interactively and you are at the top level (not in a function or loop)" does that mean that a for loop creates and uses its own environment like a function? As far as I understand .Global_Env is the environment for the interactive use of R. So when I create and run a for loop, does it create a own environment within .Global_Env?

Comment: No, a `for` loop does not have it's own environment - I was quite sloppy with terminology when I said "at the top level".